Legality of Melatonin in the UK
A friend has brought 1mg melatonin tablets into the UK for personal use.
Question 1: is that legal? is there any official website that says this?
His girlfriend then gave some to her 11-year old daughter who has trouble sleeping. She would only give her 1 tablet before bed.
Question 2: are there any legal implications for doing so?
I cannot find enough official information about this, so any help and advice is much appreciated.

What research have you done, and what questions does that leave? A quick search for "are melatonin tablets legal in uk" suggests they can not be bought and are available prescription-only.

@TripeHound Fundamentally the question would seem to be Drug X is is freely available in Country A, but in Country B it is only available via prescription.  Traveller T buys Drug X in Country A, travels to Country B, and then hands out Drug X to Person P, (who apparently is a resident of Country B).   Did T or P break any laws in Country B?

This was originally posted on skeptics where someone pointed out that Amazon UK sells melatonin. And they even have versions for kids. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57201/legality-of-melatonin-in-the-uk

@PeterM Yes, the question raises obvious questions beyond the proposed Google query. Users are well advised to read questions more carefully before offering critical comments.
